# VBA Refresh Cell Data After Applying Date Custom Format in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

[image]

I have 2 columns with the same date values and same Custom format.
Column "A" appear to be text format and column "B" appear to be date time format, which is what I want to achieve.

Column "B" is modified by "Text to Columns" tool, here is where I found this
trick: [How to Refresh Cell Data After Applying Number Formatting in Excel](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/refresh-cell-data-number-formatting-excel/)

Now, I want to make the same thing with column "A" via VBA to automate this thing.

Here is what I have tried until now and no change has been made:

Method1:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A10").Calculate
```

Method2:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A10").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"
Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited
```

Method3:

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Range("A2:A10").Select
For Each rngCell In Selection
    If IsDate(rngCell.Value) Then
      rngCell.Value2 = Format(rngCell.Value, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")
    End If
Next rngCell
```

Method4: 
I also record a macro for what I've done with column "B" and nothing happened:

```
Range("A2:A10").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Here is the Excel file: [Test.xlsb](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1938cdded24dd32c38b5b19c8ee8035820180109112511/ebe6e2356c2f537b9a45be8bd2c1b38e20180109112511/1b2535)

Comment: Another manual method which works is to press "Enter" in every cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how Excel stores dates and times.

If you select column `A` and `B` and set the formatting to "General" You'll see that column B will display a number, This is how Excel stores dates. 1 = 1-1-1900. Column A doesn't have this number in the background, it is a string, which looks like a date and so Excel cannot change it's formatting.

You'll first need to convert the contents of column `A` to a `Double` type value which is then changed by Excel's formatting to a date.

The date format of the strings in your sheet doesn't lend itself to the built in VBA string to date conversion so. I used this bit below, now it should convert properly.

```
For Each cll In Sheet1.Range("A2:A10")
    If TypeName(cll.Value) = "String" Then 'Prevents errors when the procedure is run on dates which have already been converted
        arrDateTime = Split(cll.Value, " ")

        arrDate = Split(arrDateTime(0), ".")
        dDate = DateSerial(arrDate(2), arrDate(1), arrDate(0))

        arrTime = Split(arrDateTime(1), ":")
        dTime = TimeSerial(arrTime(0), arrTime(1), 0)

        dDateTime = dDate + dTime

        cll.Value = dDateTime
    End If

Next cll
```

Comment: If I make for example cell "A2" `double` then the result is `43108.04` which in date format means `08.01.2018  00:57:36`, instead `08.01.2018  01:00:00`

Comment: @BOB I've added a solution for proper conversion.

Comment: Thank you SilentRevolution, nice solution!.

Comment: Glad I could help @BOB

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution which works:

```
Dim dat As Date

For i = 2 To 10
    Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"
    dat = Cells(i, 1).Value
    TimeValue (dat)
    Cells(i, 1).Value = dat
Next i
```

Comment: I believe this will also only work **after** the `string` type date has been converted to a `double` type number as `TimeValue("08.01.2018 01:00")` will give a type mismatch error.

Comment: Not really, for me works fine only with this code, for all of the records.